# How can you determine current storage consumption in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-storage, pricing

Given Marketing Cloud Editions have a documented storage limit with the implication over consumption will generate extra cost, how as a Marketing Cloud administrator can you determine how much space has been consumed?

Thanks

Richard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the Data Extension Storage Limit, which for the benefit of others is:

- Basic Edition: 1GB
- Pro Edition: 15GB
- Corporate Edition: 45GB
- Enterprise Edition: 100GB

The simple answer is that there is no visibility on this. It seems unusual why Marketing Cloud would impose data storage limits when there is no way of viewing your usage.

I have raised this a couple of times with an Account Manager, who informed me that this usage limit is not enforced. And I doubt they would be able to enforce it until such a time that they provide this visibility for customers.